# In Adobe Acrobat, what is the difference between Save As > "Reduce Size PDF" vs Save As > "Optimized PDF"

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

In Acrobat there are two options that appear to make files smaller;
Save As > "Reduce Size PDF"
and
Save As > "Optimized PDF"

In my tests the latter results in smaller files; which makes sense given it's name.

It's hard to track down exactly why they're different.
What do these options actually do?

Comment: Double check the help files that come with acrobat, I suspect a clear answer may be there.

Comment: One will reduce the comparability with older versions the other will reduce the size of the images

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adobe's help on [optimized pdf](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/optimizing-pdfs-acrobat-pro.html#save_using_pdf_optimizer_acrobat_pro) and [reduce size pdf](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/saving-pdfs.html#reduce_file_size_by_saving) for **acrobat XI**

Reduce size

> - resamples and recompresses images
> - Removes embedded Base-14 fonts

Optimize

> - Optimizer lets you set options for color, grayscale, and monochrome image compression, and image downsampling
> - You can also `make compatible with` to ensure certain items don't get compressed that would reduce compatibility
> - It also gives you control of other options not given in *reduce size*